# Button to start/stop an infinite loop through functions with delay between each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, loops

I'm trying to create a function that on the click of a button will start a loop through each function with a 5 second delay between each and loop infinitely until the button is clicked again.  I'm close with this, but after 5 seconds, it only just executes the last function in the set (tuesday) and does not iterate through them with a delay between each.

```
function links() {
safety
daily
monday
tuesday
}

var intervalId;
function toggleIntervalb() {

  if (!intervalId) {
    intervalId = setTimeout(links, 5000); 
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = null;
  }
}

function safety(){
document.getElementById("fires").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("safety").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("daily").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("monday").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("tuesday").style.display = 'none';

}
function daily(){
document.getElementById("fires").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("safety").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("daily").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("monday").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("tuesday").style.display = 'none';

}
function monday(){
document.getElementById("fires").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("safety").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("daily").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("monday").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("tuesday").style.display = 'none';

function tuesday(){
document.getElementById("fires").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("safety").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("daily").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("monday").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("tuesday").style.display = 'block';
```

**2nd Attempt:
Closer with this (includes button)
New to jsfiddle - can't make my code work here: https://jsfiddle.net/unqrhxtp/16

So, I am also including the pastebin (save as .html and open): https://pastebin.com/EwHVqmHJ

Currently, the code stops after executing the first function.  It appears to loop on the first element only (if you click another link manually, it forces back to the first function in the set).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated my answer below, to my understanding this will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Changing this line:

```
intervalId = setTimeout(links, 5000);
```

from a setTimeout to a setInterval will probably fix that

```
intervalId = setInterval(links, 5000);
```

### Update

After reading your updated question I think something like this will solve your problem:

```
// Gather functions in an array, easier to loop trough
var links = [
  safety,
  daily,
  monday,
  tuesday,
  wednesday,
  thursday
]

function cyclelinks() { 
  links.forEach(function(link, index) {
    var delay = index * 5000;
    var fn = links[index];
    setTimeout(fn, delay)
  });  
}

var intervalId;
function toggleInterval() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("logo");

  if (!intervalId) {
    var delay = links.length * 5000; // repeat after all functions are called with 5 sec delay
    cyclelinks()
    intervalId = setInterval(cyclelinks, delay); 
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = null;
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

Comment: use `var intervalId = setInterval(links, 5000)` and subsequently, `clearInterval(intervalId)` to stop it.

Comment: Updated OP with a working example (including button).  Hopefully this will paint the picture better of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @smelly586, your code DOES work, but seems to have the initial lag that mine has.  Takes several seconds before it starts.

Comment: Ah of course, didn't test it well. I think 2 things are happening: the setTimeout delay should start immediatly with 0 seconds delay. Also, call the `cyclelinks` funtion right before the setInterval so it starts immediatly. I've updated the snippet with these changes

Comment: And last but not least, if you want to cancel the cycle halfway, you can also store the `setTimeout` in a variable the same way you did with the `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

You should use setInterval because setTimeout runs after gived time means it works correctly because. If you  run this code step by step then you can see what i am saying.  When cursor on the settimeout your functions doesnt work immediately it will wait 5 secs.
I hope i could help

Comment: Updated OP.  Trouble with iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with a solution, although I'm not totally happy with it.  Mostly because it forces me to wait a full 90 seconds before the looping starts.  For now, this will do, but I'll leave this open in hopes someone will post a better solution.

```
//Loop through links upon click
function cyclelinks() { 
setTimeout(safety, 10000);
setTimeout(daily, 20000);
setTimeout(monday, 30000);
setTimeout(tuesday, 40000);
setTimeout(wednesday, 50000);
setTimeout(thursday, 60000);
}

var intervalId;
function toggleInterval() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("logo");

  if (!intervalId) {
    intervalId = setInterval(cyclelinks, 90000); 
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = null;
    location.reload();
  }
}
```